# Gems populator and faker in Rails app invoke errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, faker

I want to populate my database with the gems populator and faker. I just followed the [railscast tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/126-populating-a-database). If I just follow the tutorial, my code looks like:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "fill compact tables with sample data"
  task :populate => :environment do
    require 'populator'
    require 'faker'
    
    [RepositoryCompact, BuildCompact, JobCompact].each(&:delete_all)
    
    RepositoryCompact.populate 10 do |repository|
      repository.name = Faker::Name.name
      repository.description = Populator.sentences(1)
      repository.owner_name = Faker::Name.name
      repository.url = Faker::Internet.url

      i = 0 

       BuildCompact.populate 1..10 do |build|
        build.config = Populator.sentences(1..3)
        build.repository_compact_id = repository.id
        build.number = i
        i++
        build.result = 0 || 1
        build.finished_at = 2.years.ago..Time.now

         JobCompact.populate 1..5 do |job|
          job.build_compact_id = build.id
          job.allow_failure = 0 || 1
          #job.finished_at = build.finished_at-(2..100)
          job.language = [ruby, php, java, c, python, rubinius, jruby]
          job.version = [1.9 .. 2.5]
          job.result = 0 || 1
        end

       end

    end

  end
end
```

If I run `rake db:populate` the relationship seems to be not recognized by the gem (`undefined method repository_compact_id=for #<Populator::Record:0x0000010177ffb8>`)
But even if comment everything out except the RepositoryCompact part the rake aborted with `Validation failed: Name has already been taken`

I am sure I set up the models right and the associations as well.
Is there an obvious error?
Could it be that the gem `populator` is just too old?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same problem more than a few times.

Basically, when using the Populator gem, the query to insert is created in one shot, as a result when you use Faker or Populator to set values for unique columns you run into a problem.

Both gems have a limited number of permutations for generating things like emails and names, and while it's fairly large - there's always a probability that they will throw out the same name / email twice.

Since you are using Populator, there is nothing you can do to fix this issue.

An alternate, however slower approach is to use Active Record and add them by hand.

In that case you might want to try a loop which will verify uniqueness of the name before trying to save a new record with it. Like so:

```
5.times do
    repository = Repository.new
    begin
        name = Faker::Name.name
    end while Repository.where(name: name).exists?
    repository.name = name
    # set other values #
    repository.save!
end
```